# How to convert nested dictionary to flat dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a nested dictionary:

```
let dictionary1 = [
        "dof": [
            "two": "value"
        ],
        "cat" : [
            "fe": [
                "wefwef": "f"
            ]
        ]
    ]
```

And I want to get a flat dictionary with KeyPath:

```
let dictionary2 = [
    "dot.two": "value"
    "cat.fe.wefwef": "f"
]
```

Ho to make it in Swift?

Comment: Your original nested dictionary is an extremely unusual thing to have, especially in Swift. I would suggest starting by questioning how you got it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
func flatten(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [String: Any] {
  func flattenRec(output: inout [String: Any], keyPath: String, value: Any) {
    if value is String {
      output[keyPath] = value
    }
    if let dict = value as? [String: Any] {
      dict.forEach { key, value in
        flattenRec(output: &output, keyPath: "\(keyPath).\(key)", value: value)
      }
    }
  }

  var outputDict = [String: Any]()

  dictionary1.forEach { key, value in
    flattenRec(output: &outputDict, keyPath: key, value: value)
  }

  return outputDict
}

let output = flatten(dictionary: dictionary1)
```